# How to parse and search a list of inter-dependent strings?

Tags: python, list, search

Not sure how to word the title but I have this list:

```
Sink Input #1535
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 10
    Client: 21932
    Sink: 0
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"s16le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 32768 /  50% / -18.06 dB,   front-right: 32768 /  50% / -18.06 dB
            balance 0.00
    Buffer Latency: 0 usec
    Sink Latency: 23084 usec
    Resample method: n/a
    Properties:
        media.name = "Simple DirectMedia Layer"
        application.name = "ffplay"
```

with a whole bunch of other stuff following.

First I need to match on `Input Sink#` and record the following digits until end of line. Then I have to search on `application.name =`  and record the program name that follows in quotes. Then the search has to repeat for multiple sinks and program names. Later I plan to return all Input Sink numbers for a given application name.

Current method uses brute force and high system resources. Is there a better method than this:

```
def sink_list(prog,func):
    ''' Return list of Firefox or ffplay input sinks indices
    '''
    indices = []
    result = os.popen('pactl list short sink-inputs') \
                      .read().strip().splitlines()

    # TODO: We could be doing one os.popen and grabbing all sinks at once
    if len(result) == 0:
        print('sink_list() found no input sinks at all.' \
              '  Called by: '+func)
        return indices

    for line in result:
        sink = line.split('\t')[0]
        app = os.popen('pactl list sink-inputs | grep "Sink Input #' + \
                        sink + '" -A20 | grep application.name').read()
#        print("Searching for:",prog," in:",app," using input sink#:",sink)
        if prog in app:
            indices.append(sink)

#        print('indices',prog,':',indices)
    if len(indices) == 0:
        print("sink_list() found no input sink for: '" + prog + \
              "' called by: "+func)
        return indices
#    print("Found Input Sinks:", indices)
    return indices
```

### Reply to comments

Input was requested:

```
    ''' Get old PID's and Input Sinks before ffplay '''
    old_pid = pid_list( "ffplay", "play_start()" )
    old_sink = sink_list( "ffplay", "play_start()" )
    self.have_ffplay_input_sink = False     # Each ffplay can have diff #

    # Launch ffplay in the background. CANNOT query result, it stops bkgrnd
    os.popen('ffplay -autoexit ' + '"' + self.current_song_path + '"' \
                 + ' -nodisp 2>' + TMP_CURR_SONG + ' &')

    ''' Get New PID's and Input Sinks for ffplay '''
    # Give time for `ffplay` to create pulseaudio sink.
    root.after(100)      # THIS IS UGLY, root.after is machine dependent!!!
    if not self.top2_is_active: return          # Play window closed?

    new_pid = pid_list("ffplay", "play_start()")
    new_sink = sink_list("ffplay", "play_start()")
    self.top2_ffplay_pid = list_diff(new_pid, old_pid, "play_start()")
    self.top2_ffplay_sink = list_diff(new_sink, old_sink, "play_start()")
```

Comment: Take a look at python's `in` operator. It implements the portion of `grep` that you need.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for that tip. I use `grep` all over the place in my last Python program and this my second program. I've only been coding in bash for four years.

Comment: Python is generally more versatile than bash. You'll like it once you get used to it

Comment: Can you show a sample output for multiple sinks?

Comment: @MadPhysicist It will be a list like `['1509', '1514']` (if I understood your question right). Yes this application was first in bash and then took like 45 seconds for 1,000 songs and would crash after. Python is like 1 second for 5,000 songs and doesn't crash. I make lots of "oops" learning "OOP" though :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant program output. So input I guess

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm not sure how it's relevant but I updated question with  input if I understood correctly.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If you are interested, I've answered my own question today.

Comment: Seems like a good way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question in case it helps others.

This is the function I wrote which returns original requirements plus current volume:

```
def sink_master():
    all_lines = []
    all_lines = os.popen('pactl list sink-inputs').read().splitlines()

    all_sinks = []
    in_sink = False
    in_volume = False
    for line in all_lines:
        if in_sink is False and "Sink Input #" in line:
            this_sink = line.split('#')[1]
            in_sink = True
            continue
        if in_sink is True and in_volume is False and "Volume:" in line:
            this_volume = line.split('/')[1]
            this_volume = this_volume.replace(' ','')
            this_volume = this_volume.replace('%','')
            in_volume = True
            continue
        if in_sink is True and in_volume is True and "tion.name =" in line:
            this_name = line.split('=')[1]
            this_name = this_name.replace(' ','')
            this_name = this_name.replace('"','')
            in_sink = False
            in_volume = False
            all_sinks.append(tuple((this_sink,this_volume,this_name)))
            continue

    print(all_sinks)
    return all_sinks
```

When you run it it returns a list of tuples:

```
[('1828', '100', 'Firefox'), ('1891', '50', 'ffplay'), ('1907', '100', 'ffplay')]
```

Each tuple contains:

1. Input Sink # used by `pulseaudio` (respected by `ffplay`)
2. Current volume (with spaces and `%` stripped)
3. Application name (with double quotes `"` stripped)